# How should I keep the sharing variables in android?

Tags: android, oop, model

The work flow of my program is:

1. Launch app

   - Splash screen, check the server api, from the api get a list of file name
   - Download some of the file in file list , remove the downloaded file name from the list
2. App opened

   - when the download is finished , jump to main page that will start download another file in the list

The problem is , the list I was keep in the download manager , when I select don't leave activities in android setting , it will be killed. If I need a class that is some Data Class , that means I put a share data (A several hash map , array list) in it, and it keep updating (delete after async download finish) , and it never get killed. How can it be done? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The more general problem you are encountering is how to save state across several Activities and all parts of your application. A static variable (for instance, a singleton) is a common Java way of achieving this. I have found however, that a more elegant way in Android is to associate your state with the Application context. As you know, each Activity is also a Context, which is information about its execution environment in the broadest sense. Your application also has a context, and Android guarantees that it will exist as a single instance across your application. The way to do this is to create your own subclass of `android.app.Application`, and then specify that class in the application tag in your manifest. Now Android will automatically create an instance of that class and make it available for your entire application. You can access it from any context using the `Context.getApplicationContext()` method (Activity also provides a method `getApplication()` which has the exact same effect):

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    private String myState;
    public String getState() {
        return myState;
    }
    public void setState(String s) {
        myState = s;
    }
}
class Blah extends Activity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        ...
        MyApp appState = ((MyApp) getApplicationContext());
        String state = appState.getState();
        ...
    }
}
```

This has essentially the same effect as using a static variable or singleton, but integrates quite well into the existing Android framework. Note that this will not work across processes (should your app be one of the rare ones that has multiple processes).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why I can not simply create a constant class and put the variable inside it, make it static? It seems the class is null pointer when I open the app again . Thanks